# What does GetFunctionPointerForDelegate convert a String^ parameter in a delegate into?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to convert a C# delegate to a C++ function pointer, using Managed C++.  Here's the method we were previously using:

```
// Define a delegate
public delegate void ADelegate(Int32);
ADelegate^ delegateInstance;

// Define a function pointer
typedef void (__stdcall *AFuntionPointer)(int);
AFuntionPointer functionPointerInstance;

// Create an instance of a delegate, using GetFunctionPointerForDelegate
delegateInstance = gcnew ADelegate(this, &AClass::AFunction);

// Convert the delegate to a pointer
IntPtr anIntPtr = Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegateInstance);

// Cast the pointer into a function pointer
functionPointerInstance = static_cast<AFuntionPointer>(anIntPtr.ToPointer());
```

If I turn the `ADelegate`'s parameter from an `Int32` to a `String^`, to what type should I change the `AFunctionPointer`'s parameter to?  In another words, if I changed the first two lines in the above code to:

```
public delegate void ADelegate(String ^);
ADelegate^ delegateInstance;
```

How should I change the next two lines?

```
// To what type does GetFunctionPointerForDelegate translate String^ to?
typedef void (__stdcall *AFuntionPointer)( /* char*?  std::string? */ );
AFuntionPointer functionPointerInstance;
```

Comment: This looks more like C++/CLI than Managed C++...

Comment: Is the argument `const char*` or `char*`?  Very big difference.

Comment: Actually, that is my question.  What is the valid argument?  Is it `char*`, `const char*`, `std::string`, `Cstring`, etc?

Comment: I've update the above text to better indicate that is my question, rather than part of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() on that delegate would generate a function pointer that's compatible with

```
  typedef void (__stdcall *AFuntionPointer)( const char* );
```

`String^` marshals to `const char*` unless a [MarshalAs] attribute is applied to the delegate argument.  Marshaling directly to std::string is not possible, the pinvoke marshaller doesn't know anything about C++ object layout for classes that are declared in a header file.